# Swift scale-transform animation accidentally translates UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

Simple question really. I'm using a UIView animation to have my button shrink and grow based on user input:

```
private func animateSelect() {
    guard !isAnimating else {
        return
    }
    
    alpha = 0.8
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
    }
    isAnimating = true
}

private func animateDeselect() {
    guard isAnimating else {
        return
    }
    
    alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.transform = .identity
    }
    isAnimating = false
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    animateSelect()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

    animateDeselect()
}
```

And I thought I arranged everything to avoid conflicting layouts or animations using the `isAnimating` variable - guarded on `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    guard !isAnimating else {
        return
    }
    
...
```

But the button translates with the animation. It's really annoying, breaks the smoothness and I'm a bit confused as subtracting translation from the transform inside the animation didn't solve it. Anybody have tips on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Looking closer, it seems that you don't need `isAnimating` at all. Something like this should be fine:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    private func animateSelect() {
        alpha = 0.8
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }
    }
    
    private func animateDeselect() {
        alpha = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.transform = .identity
        }
    }
}
```

**Except**, the problem most likely is the **`self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)`**. When the transform is not `.identity`, the `frame` gets messed up. So for example, when you are initializing `MyView`:

```
let myView = MyView()
myView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 60, width: 100, height: 200)
```

... here, `myView.frame` may not be accurate.

Inside `MyView`, you should make a new subview, `contentView`. This will contain the stuff that you want to scale. Something like this:

```
/// usage
let myView = MyView()
myView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 50, height: 100)
myView.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
view.addSubview(myView)
```

```
/// code
class MyView: UIView {
    var contentView: UIView!
    
    private func animateSelect() {
        alpha = 0.8
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.contentView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }
    }
    
    private func animateDeselect() {
        alpha = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.contentView?.transform = .identity
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Init methods
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    // MARK: Set up the contentView
    private func commonInit() {
        let contentView = UIView()
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.contentView = contentView
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        animateSelect()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        animateDeselect()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Red rectangle animating scale when pressed]

---

Old answer:

Use the completion handler to reset `isAnimating` once the animation is done. Also, there's no need to check `guard isAnimating else { return }`... UIView animations usually automatically sort that out for you.

```
private func animateSelect() {
    alpha = 0.8
    isAnimating = true /// put it in front so that it's easier to read
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
    } completion: { _ in /// set the completion handler
        self.isAnimating = false
    }
}

private func animateDeselect() {
    alpha = 1.0
    isAnimating = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.transform = .identity
    } completion: { _ in
        self.isAnimating = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, awesome answer! In fact I think the contentView is a great idea that will spare me issues like this in the future. I'll report back if there are problems applying it, but it should work.